# How to delete a registry key from a remote computer under Current User or Users SID

Tags: vbscript, key, registry, remote-execution

I am trying to create a script that performs the below steps:

1. Enter Remote machine name
2. Enter User's Domain and  User name (DOMAIN1\USERNAME)
3. Run WMI query to obtain SID
4. Open either HKEY_CURRENT_USER (or HKEY_USERS and locate SID)
5. Delete Key variable key from defined strKeyPath , in this case = "Software\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\Safer\CodeIdentifiers\0\Paths"

```
On Error Resume Next

Function GetSIDFromUser(UserName)
  Dim DomainName, Result, WMIUser

  If InStr(UserName, "DOMAIN1\") > 0 Or InStr(UserName, "DOMAIN2\") > 0 Then
    DomainName = Mid(UserName, 1, InStr(UserName, "\") - 1)
    UserName = Mid(UserName, InStr(UserName, "\") + 1)
  Else
    WScript.Echo "ERROR: Please add user's domain. Format DOMAIN1\USERNAME "
    WScript.quit
  End If

  On Error Resume Next
  Set WMIUser = GetObject("winmgmts:{impersonationlevel=impersonate}!" _
    & "/root/cimv2:Win32_UserAccount.Domain='" & DomainName & "'" _
    & ",Name='" & UserName & "'")
  If Err = 0 Then Result = WMIUser.SID Else Result = ""
  On Error GoTo 0
  GetSIDFromUser = Result
End Function 


'Constants
    Const HKEY_CURRENT_USER = &H80000001
    Const HKEY_USERS        = &H80000003

'Input

    strComputer = UCase(InputBox("Please enter the Computer Name:", "Outlook Policy - Remote Fix"))
    strUser = UCase(InputBox("Please enter the User Name:", "Outlook Policy - Remote Fix")) 
    If (strcomputer <> vbnullstring) Then
    If (strUser <> vbnullstring) Then

    strSID = GetSIDFromUser(strUser)

    'Set objRegistry = GetObject("winmgmts:\\" & _
            'strComputer & "\root\default:StdRegProv") 

    Set objRegistry = GetObject("winmgmts:{impersonationLevel=impersonate}!\\" & _
        strComputer & "\root\default:StdRegProv")

'Path
    
    'strKeyPath = "Software\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\Safer\CodeIdentifiers\0\Paths"

'Test Path  

    strKeyPath = "Software\Test"

'Delete keys and subkeys

    DeleteSubkeys HKEY_CURRENT_USER, strKeypath 

    Sub DeleteSubkeys(HKEY_CURRENT_USER, strKeyPath) 
            'objRegistry.EnumKey HKEY_CURRENT_USER, strKeyPath, arrSubkeys 

        If IsArray(arrSubkeys) Then 
            For Each strSubkey In arrSubkeys 
                    DeleteSubkeys HKEY_CURRENT_USER, strKeyPath & "\" & strSubkey 
            Next 
        End If 

        objRegistry.DeleteKey HKEY_CURRENT_USER, strKeyPath 
    End Sub


'Error reporting

    If Err <> 0 Then
    WScript.Echo "Error Number: " & Err.Number  & VBNewLine &  Err.Description
        Err.Clear
    Else
        WScript.Echo "Success! The Outlook policy has now been updated. Please instruct the user to restart the computer, for this policy to take effect."
    End If
End if
End if
```

Answer (score 0):

PS You haven't specified any problem, giving any error description, or error numbers. WMI returns 0 for sucess and a wbemerrorenum for failure. That's at the bottom of the post.

WMi doesn't do HKCU remotely. From Help

> The registry provider for Windows Server 2003 is hosted in LocalService—not the LocalSystem. Therefore, using the Windows Server 2003 family you cannot obtain information remotely from HKEY_CURRENT_USER, but you can run scripts locally. You can set the hosting model to LocalSystem on a remote machine, but the remote machine registry is vulnerable to hostile access, which is a security risk.

If it did it would only do current logged on user as that is HKCU. Therefore you don't need their username.

If you want a non logged on user (remotely) then it doesn't seem possible as a Reg command (see reg load /?) or WMI (no load profile command).

This will load a user profile. LOCALLY

```
reg load hku\tempkeyname "C:\Users\Admin with UAC\NTUSER.DAT"
```

This will run a command on another computer (notice escaping of " and \ with a \) loading a profile

```
wmic /node:127.0.0.1 process call create "reg load hku\\tempkeyname \"C:\\Users\\Admin with UAC\\NTUSER.DAT""




WbemErrorEnum

The WbemErrorEnum constants define the errors that may be returned by Scripting API for WMI calls.

The WMI scripting type library wbemdisp.tlb defines these constants. Visual Basic applications can access this library; script languages must use the value of the constant directly, unless they use the Windows Script Host (WSH) XML file format. For more information, see Using the WMI Scripting Type Library.



Constant/value Description 
wbemNoErr
0
0x0 The call was successful. 
wbemErrFailed
2147749889
0x80041001 The call failed. 
wbemErrNotFound
2147749890 The object could not be found. 
wbemErrAccessDenied
2147749891
0x80041003 The current user does not have permission to perform the action. 
wbemErrProviderFailure
2147749892
0x80041004 The provider has failed at some time other than during initialization. 
wbemErrTypeMismatch
2147749893
0x80041005 A type mismatch occurred. 
wbemErrOutOfMemory
2147749894
0x80041006 There was not enough memory for the operation. 
wbemErrInvalidContext
2147749895
0x80041007 The SWbemNamedValue object is not valid. 
wbemErrInvalidParameter
2147749896
0x80041008 One of the parameters to the call is not correct. 
wbemErrNotAvailable
2147749897
0x80041009 The resource, typically a remote server, is not currently available. 
wbemErrCriticalError
2147749898
0x8004100A An internal, critical, and unexpected error occurred. Report this error to Microsoft Technical Support. 
wbemErrInvalidStream
2147749899
0x8004100B One or more network packets were corrupted during a remote session. 
wbemErrNotSupported
2147749900
0x8004100C The feature or operation is not supported. 
wbemErrInvalidSuperclass
2147749901
0x8004100D The parent class specified is not valid. 
wbemErrInvalidNamespace
2147749902
0x8004100E The namespace specified could not be found. 
wbemErrInvalidObject
2147749903
0x8004100F The specified instance is not valid. 
wbemErrInvalidClass
2147749904
0x80041010 The specified class is not valid. 
wbemErrProviderNotFound
2147749905
0x80041011 A provider referenced in the schema does not have a corresponding registration. 
wbemErrInvalidProviderRegistration
2147749906
0x80041012 A provider referenced in the schema has an incorrect or incomplete registration. This error may be caused by a missing pragma namespace command in the MOF file used to register the provider, resulting in the provider being registered in the wrong WMI namespace. This error may also be caused by a corrupt repository, which may be fixed by deleting it and recompiling the MOF files. 
wbemErrProviderLoadFailure
2147749907
0x80041013 COM cannot locate a provider referenced in the schema. This error may be caused by any of the following: 
The provider is using a WMI DLL that does not match the .lib fileused when the provider was built.

The provider's DLL or any of the DLLs on which it depends is corrupt.

The provider failed to export DllRegisterServer.

An in-process provider was not registered using /regsvr32.

An out-of-process provider was not registered using /regserver.

wbemErrInitializationFailure
2147749908
0x80041014 A component, such as a provider, failed to initialize for internal reasons. 
wbemErrTransportFailure
2147749909
0x80041015 A networking error occurred, preventing normal operation. 
wbemErrInvalidOperation
2147749910
0x80041016 The requested operation is not valid. This error usually applies to invalid attempts to delete classes or properties. 
wbemErrInvalidQuery
2147749911
0x80041017 The requested operation is not valid. This error usually applies to invalid attempts to delete classes or properties. 
wbemErrInvalidQueryType
2147749912
0x80041018 The requested query language is not supported. 
wbemErrAlreadyExists
2147749913
0x80041019 In a put operation, the wbemChangeFlagCreateOnly flag was specified, but the instance already exists. 
wbemErrOverrideNotAllowed
2147749914
0x8004101A It is not possible to perform the add operation on this qualifier because the owning object does not permit overrides. 
wbemErrPropagatedQualifier
2147749915
0x8004101B The user attempted to delete a qualifier that was not owned. The qualifier was inherited from a parent class. 
wbemErrPropagatedProperty
2147749916
0x8004101C The user attempted to delete a property that was not owned. The property was inherited from a parent class. 
wbemErrUnexpected
2147749917
0x8004101D The client made an unexpected and illegal sequence of calls, such as calling EndEnumeration before calling BeginEnumeration. 
wbemErrIllegalOperation
2147749918
0x8004101E The user requested an illegal operation, such as spawning a class from an instance. 
wbemErrCannotBeKey
2147749919
0x8004101F There was an illegal attempt to specify a key qualifier on a property that cannot be a key. The keys are specified in the class definition for an object, and cannot be altered on a per-instance basis. 
wbemErrIncompleteClass
2147749920
0x80041020 The current object is not a valid class definition. Either it is incomplete, or it has not been registered with WMI using SWbemObject.Put_. 
wbemErrInvalidSyntax
2147749921
0x80041021 The syntax of an input parameter is incorrect for the applicable data structure. For example, when a CIM datetime structure does not have the correct format when passed to SWbemDateTime.SetFileTime. 
wbemErrNondecoratedObject
2147749922
0x80041022 Reserved for future use. 
wbemErrReadOnly
2147749923
0x80041023 The property that you are attempting to modify is read-only. 
wbemErrProviderNotCapable
2147749924
0x80041024 The provider cannot perform the requested operation. This would include a query that is too complex, retrieving an instance, creating or updating a class, deleting a class, or enumerating a class. 
wbemErrClassHasChildren
2147749925
0x80041025 An attempt was made to make a change that would invalidate a subclass. 
wbemErrClassHasInstances
2147749926
0x80041026 An attempt has been made to delete or modify a class that has instances. 
wbemErrQueryNotImplemented
2147749927
0x80041027 Reserved for future use. 
wbemErrIllegalNull
2147749928
0x80041028 A value of Nothing was specified for a property that may not be Nothing, such as one that is marked by a Key, Indexed, or Not_Null qualifier. 
wbemErrInvalidQualifierType
2147749929
0x80041029 The CIM type specified for a property is not valid. 
wbemErrInvalidPropertyType
2147749930
0x8004102A The CIM type specified for a property is not valid. 
wbemErrValueOutOfRange
2147749931
0x8004102B The request was made with an out-of-range value, or is incompatible with the type. 
wbemErrCannotBeSingleton
2147749932
0x8004102C An illegal attempt was made to make a class singleton, such as when the class is derived from a non-singleton class. 
wbemErrInvalidCimType
2147749933
0x8004102D The CIM type specified is not valid. 
wbemErrInvalidMethod
2147749934
0x8004102E The requested method is not available. 
wbemErrInvalidMethodParameters
2147749935
0x8004102F The parameters provided for the method are not valid. 
wbemErrSystemProperty
2147749936
0x80041030 There was an attempt to get qualifiers on a system property. 
wbemErrInvalidProperty
2147749937
0x80041031 The property type is not recognized. 
wbemErrCallCancelled
2147749938
0x80041032 An asynchronous process has been canceled internally or by the user. Note that due to the timing and nature of the asynchronous operation the operation may not have been truly canceled. 
wbemErrShuttingDown
2147749939
0x80041033 The user has requested an operation while WMI is in the process of shutting down. 
wbemErrPropagatedMethod
2147749940
0x80041034 An attempt was made to reuse an existing method name from a parent class, and the signatures did not match. 
wbemErrUnsupportedParameter
2147749941
0x80041035 One or more parameter values, such as a query text, is too complex or unsupported. WMI is therefore requested to retry the operation with simpler parameters. 
wbemErrMissingParameter
2147749942
0x80041036 A parameter was missing from the method call. 
wbemErrInvalidParameterId
2147749943
0x80041037 A method parameter has an invalid ID qualifier. 
wbemErrNonConsecutiveParameterIds
2147749944
0x80041038 One or more of the method parameters have ID qualifiers that are out of sequence. 
wbemErrParameterIdOnRetval
2147749945
0x80041039 The return value for a method has an ID qualifier. 
wbemErrInvalidObjectPath
2147749946
0x8004103A The specified object path was invalid. 
wbemErrOutOfDiskSpace
2147749947 Windows XP/2000/NT:  Disk is out of space.
Windows Server 2003:  Disk is out of space or the 4 GB limit on WMI repository (CIM repository) size is reached. 
wbemErrBufferTooSmall
2147749948
0x8004103C The supplied buffer was too small to hold all the objects in the enumerator or to read a string property. 
wbemErrUnsupportedPutExtension
2147749949
0x8004103D The provider does not support the requested put operation. 
wbemErrUnknownObjectType
2147749950
0x8004103E An object with an incorrect type or version was encountered during marshaling. 
wbemErrUnknownPacketType
2147749951
0x8004103F A packet with an incorrect type or version was encountered during marshaling. 
wbemErrMarshalVersionMismatch
2147749952
0x80041040 The packet has an unsupported version. 
wbemErrMarshalInvalidSignature
2147749953
0x80041041 The packet appears to be corrupted. 
wbemErrInvalidQualifier
2147749954
0x80041042 An attempt has been made to mismatch qualifiers, such as putting [key] on an object instead of a property. 
wbemErrInvalidDuplicateParameter
2147749955
0x80041043 A duplicate parameter has been declared in a CIM method. 
wbemErrTooMuchData
2147749956
0x80041044 Reserved for future use. 
wbemErrServerTooBusy
2147749957
0x80041045 A call to IWbemObjectSink::Indicate has failed. The provider may choose to refire the event. 
wbemErrInvalidFlavor
2147749958
0x80041046 The specified flavor was invalid. 
wbemErrCircularReference
2147749959
0x80041047 An attempt has been made to create a reference that is circular (for example, deriving a class from itself). 
wbemErrUnsupportedClassUpdate
2147749960 The specified class is not supported. 
wbemErrCannotChangeKeyInheritance
2147749961
0x80041049 An attempt was made to change a key when instances or subclasses are already using the key. 
wbemErrCannotChangeIndexInheritance
2147749968
0x80041050 An attempt was made to change an index when instances or subclasses are already using the index. 
wbemErrTooManyProperties
2147749969
0x80041051 An attempt was made to create more properties than the current version of the class supports. 
wbemErrUpdateTypeMismatch
2147749970
0x80041052 A property was redefined with a conflicting type in a derived class. 
wbemErrUpdateOverrideNotAllowed
2147749971
0x80041053 An attempt was made in a derived class to override a non-overrideable qualifier. 
wbemErrUpdatePropagatedMethod
2147749972
0x80041054 A method was redeclared with a conflicting signature in a derived class. 
wbemErrMethodNotImplemented
2147749973
0x80041055 An attempt was made to execute a method not marked with [implemented] in any relevant class. 
wbemErrMethodDisabled
2147749974
0x80041056 An attempt was made to execute a method marked with [disabled]. 
wbemErrRefresherBusy
2147749975
0x80041057 The refresher is busy with another operation. 
wbemErrUnparsableQuery
2147749976
0x80041058 The filtering query is syntactically invalid. 
wbemErrNotEventClass
2147749977
0x80041059 The FROM clause of a filtering query references a class that is not an event class (not derived from __Event). 
wbemErrMissingGroupWithin
2147749978
0x8004105A A GROUP BY clause was used without the corresponding GROUP WITHIN clause. 
wbemErrMissingAggregationList
2147749979
0x8004105B A GROUP BY clause was used. Aggregation on all properties is not supported. 
wbemErrPropertyNotAnObject
2147749980
0x8004105C Dot notation was used on a property that is not an embedded object. 
wbemErrAggregatingByObject
2147749981
0x8004105D A GROUP BY clause references a property that is an embedded object without using dot notation. 
wbemErrUninterpretableProviderQuery
2147749983
0x8004105F An event provider registration query ( __EventProviderRegistration) did not specify the classes for which events were provided. 
wbemErrBackupRestoreWinmgmtRunning
2147749984
0x80041060 An request was made to back up or restore the repository while WMI was using it. 
wbemErrQueueOverflow
2147749985
0x80041061 The asynchronous delivery queue overflowed due to the event consumer being too slow. 
wbemErrPrivilegeNotHeld
2147749986
0x80041062 The operation failed because the client did not have the necessary security privilege. 
wbemErrInvalidOperator
2147749987
0x80041063 The operator is not valid for this property type. 
wbemErrLocalCredentials
2147749988
0x80041064 The user specified a username, password or authority for a local connection. The user must use a blank username/password and rely on default security. 
wbemErrCannotBeAbstract
2147749989
0x80041065 The class was made abstract when its parent class is not abstract. 
wbemErrAmendedObject
2147749990
0x80041066 An amended object was put without the wbemFlagUseAmendedQualifiers flag being specified. 
wbemErrClientTooSlow
2147749991
0x80041067 Windows Server 2003 and Windows XP:  The client was not retrieving objects quickly enough from an enumeration. This constant is returned when a client creates an enumeration object but does not retrieve objects from the enumerator in a timely fashion, causing the enumerator's object caches to get backed up. 
wbemErrNullSecurityDescriptor
2147749992
0x80041068 Windows Server 2003 and Windows XP:  A null security descriptor was used. 
wbemErrTimeout
2147749993
0x80041069 Windows Server 2003 and Windows XP:  The operation timed out. 
wbemErrInvalidAssociation
2147749994
0x8004106A Windows Server 2003 and Windows XP:  The association being used is not valid. 
wbemErrAmbiguousOperation
2147749995
0x8004106B Windows Server 2003 and Windows XP:  The operation was ambiguous. 
wbemErrQuotaViolation
2147749996
0x8004106C Windows Server 2003 and Windows XP:  WMI is taking up too much memory. This could be caused either by low memory availability or excessive memory consumption by WMI. 
wbemErrTransactionConflict
2147749997
0x8004106D Windows Server 2003 and Windows XP:  The operation resulted in a transaction conflict. 
wbemErrForcedRollback
2147749998
0x8004106E Windows Server 2003 and Windows XP:  The transaction forced a rollback. 
wbemErrUnsupportedLocale
2147749999
0x8004106F Windows Server 2003 and Windows XP:  The locale used in the call is not supported. 
wbemErrHandleOutOfDate
2147750000
0x80041070 Windows Server 2003 and Windows XP:  The object handle is out of date. 
wbemErrConnectionFailed
2147750001
0x80041071 Windows Server 2003 and Windows XP:  Indicates that the connection to the SQL database failed. 
wbemErrInvalidHandleRequest
2147750002
0x80041072 Windows Server 2003 and Windows XP:  The handle request was invalid. 
wbemErrPropertyNameTooWide
2147750003
0x80041073 Windows Server 2003 and Windows XP:  The property name contains more than 255 characters. 
wbemErrClassNameTooWide
2147750004
0x80041074 Windows Server 2003 and Windows XP:  The class name contains more than 255 characters. 
wbemErrMethodNameTooWide
2147750005
0x80041075 Windows Server 2003 and Windows XP:  The method name contains more than 255 characters. 
wbemErrQualifierNameTooWide
2147750006
0x80041076 Windows Server 2003 and Windows XP:  The qualifier name contains more than 255 characters. 
wbemErrRerunCommand
2147750007
0x80041077 Windows Server 2003 and Windows XP:  Indicates that an SQL command should be rerun because there is a deadlock in SQL. This can be returned only when data is being stored in an SQL database. 
wbemErrDatabaseVerMismatch
2147750008
0x80041078 Windows Server 2003 and Windows XP:  The database version does not match the version that the repository driver understands. 
wbemErrVetoDelete
2147750010
0x8004107A Windows Server 2003 and Windows XP:  WMI cannot do the delete operation because the provider does not allow it. 
wbemErrVetoPut
2147750010
0x8004107A Windows Server 2003 and Windows XP:  WMI cannot do the put operation because the provider does not allow it. 
wbemErrInvalidLocale
2147750016
0x80041080 Windows Server 2003 and Windows XP:  The specified locale identifier was not valid for the operation. 
wbemErrProviderSuspended
2147750017
0x80041081 Windows Server 2003 and Windows XP:  The provider is suspended. 
wbemErrSynchronizationRequired
2147750018
0x80041082 Windows Server 2003 and Windows XP:  The object must be committed and retrieved again before the requested operation can succeed. This constant is returned when an object must be committed and re-retrieved to see the property value. 
wbemErrNoSchema
2147750019
0x80041083 Windows Server 2003 and Windows XP:  The operation cannot be completed because no schema is available. 
wbemErrProviderAlreadyRegistered
2147750020
0x80041084 Windows Server 2003 and Windows XP:  The provider registration cannot be done because the provider is already registered. 
wbemErrProviderNotRegistered
2147750021
0x80041085 Windows Server 2003 and Windows XP:  The provider for the requested data is not registered. 
wbemErrFatalTransportError
2147750022
0x80041086 Windows Server 2003 and Windows XP:  A fatal transport error occurred and other transport will not be attempted. 
wbemErrEncryptedConnectionRequired
2147750023
0x80041087 Windows Server 2003 and Windows XP:  The client connection to WINMGMT must be encrypted for this operation. The IWbemServices proxy security settings should be adjusted and the operation retried. 
See WBEM_E_PROVIDER_TIMED_OUT in WMI Error Constants
2147750024
0x80041088 Windows Server 2003 and Windows XP:  A provider failed to report results within the specified timeout. 
See WBEM_E_NO_KEY in WMI Error Constants
2147750025
0x80041089 Windows Server 2003 and Windows XP:  User attempted to put an instance with no defined key. 
See WBEM_E_PROVIDER_DISABLED in WMI Error Constants
2147750026
0x8004108A Windows Server 2003 and Windows XP:  User attempted to register a provider instance but the COM server for the provider instance was unloaded. 
wbemErrRegistrationTooBroad
2147753985
0x80042001 Windows Server 2003 and Windows XP:  The provider registration overlaps with the system event domain. 
wbemErrRegistrationTooPrecise
2147753986
0x80042002 Windows Server 2003 and Windows XP:  A WITHIN clause was not used in this query. 
wbemErrTimedout
2147758081
0x80043001 Windows Server 2003 and Windows XP:  Automation-specific error. 
wbemErrResetToDefault
2147758082
0x80043002 Windows Server 2003 and Windows XP:  The user deleted an override default value for the current class. The default value for this property in the parent class has been reactivated. An automation-specific error. 

Requirements
Client Requires Windows Vista, Windows XP, Windows 2000 Professional, Windows NT Workstation 4.0 SP4 and later, or Windows Me. 
Server Requires Windows Server "Longhorn", Windows Server 2003, Windows 2000 Server, or Windows NT Server 4.0 SP4 and later. 
Header Declared in Wbemdisp.h.

IDL Declared in Wbemdisp.idl.


See Also
Scripting API Constants



Send comments about this topic to Microsoft

Build date: 10/2/2006
Requirements
Client Requires Windows Vista, Windows XP, Windows 2000 Professional, Windows NT Workstation 4.0 SP4 and later, or Windows Me. 
Server Requires Windows Server "Longhorn", Windows Server 2003, Windows 2000 Server, or Windows NT Server 4.0 SP4 and later. 
Header Declared in Wbemdisp.h.

IDL Declared in Wbemdisp.idl.

See Also
Scripting API Constants



Send comments about this topic to Microsoft

Build date: 10/2/2006
```